# auto install minecraft script

Tags: ubuntu, scripting, test, minecraft

So I was working on this script to auto install minecraft and i began to wonder is there a better way to do this?

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get autoclean

echo " Jobs Done!"


sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt update; sudo apt install oracle-java8-installer
sudo apt install oracle-java8-set-default
sudo apt-get install default-jre
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:flexiondotorg/minecraft
sudo apt-get install minecraft-installer
sudo apt-get autoclean



echo "This world is about to get crafty!"


cd .minecraft
chmod 777 launcher.jar
java -Xmx3G -Xms3G -jar launcher.jar
```

The reason I ask is I wanted to make a way to easily install and then open minecraft for my friends that are a little less tech savy but could at least run a script. Would be curious the thought on the matter.

Comment: Do you want to see the output of the apt commands or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the repositories first (make shure that they are trustworthy), then update, upgrade everything.

(Note: that you should update first and then upgrade, because the other way around, nothing will happen.)

The `-y` flags should prevent `apt` from asking every time. `apt-install` allows multiple packages to be specified.

The permissions `750` should suffice.

This should work (further explainations in the script comments):

```
#!/bin/bash

#add repos
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java -y
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:flexiondotorg/minecraft -y

#make sure everything is up-to-date
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade -y

#install the packages
sudo apt install -y oracle-java8-installer oracle-java8-set-default default-jre minecraft-installer

#cleanup (not necessarily required)
sudo apt-get autoclean

echo "This world is about to get crafty!"

#if the .minecraft folder is located under /home/username/.minecraft, you should use ~/.minecraft
#temporarily change directory
pushd ~/.minecraft

#set permissions
chmod 750 launcher.jar

#start application in background, in order to finish script, the '&' is responsible for that
java -Xmx3G -Xms3G -jar launcher.jar &

#undo temporary directory change
popd
```

Answer (score 0):

You can improve this by atleast checking the return codes of your commands (i.e. making sure everything worked). You can do this with either `&&` or the special variable `$?`.

Also, why not add all the repos first, then do `apt update` only once? This should save some time.

`chmod 777` is pretty much always a bad idea, giving the user execution rights should be enough.